# Как исправить ошибку Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api, google-maps

На этом [сайте](https://israel-escorts.com/), на некоторых страницах возникает JS предупреждение *Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys* и ошибка **Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error**. В Google Maps API стоит разрешение - [https://israel-escorts.com/*](https://israel-escorts.com/), но карты нормально не работают... Как исправить эту ошибку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С API ключом вроде все ОК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотрите в исходном коде страницы, как запускается скрипт карты, указан ли там ключ. Есл нет, ищите запуск через wp_enqueue_script() в вашей теме enfold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была из-за конфликта с плагином ACF. Вот код, который решает проблему:

```
function my_acf_google_map_api( $api ){
    $api['key'] = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
    return $api;
}
add_filter('acf/fields/google_map/api', 'my_acf_google_map_api');
```